# EditText(android.content.Context) in EditText cannot be applied to (android.view.View)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to make a username and password for security purposes to enter my app. I tried setting the username and password as objects but it is giving me the above error.

Any clues?

I am using android studio

```
package com.example.xfrehner1.jacksonattendance;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
public class LogIn extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_log_in);
    }
    /*Creates objects for the username and password*/
    EditText username = new EditText(findViewById(R.id.userEditText));//it highlights this red
    EditText password = new EditText(findViewById(R.id.passEditText));//this too

    //AlertDialog wrongUP = new AlertDialog.Builder(LogIn.this).create();
    //wrongUP.setTitle("Error");

    public void enterUPButton(View v){
        Intent afterLog= new Intent(this, firstScreen.class);
        if(username.getText().toString().equals("admin") && password.getText().toString().equals("Password1234")){
            startActivity(afterLog);
        }else{
            System.exit(0);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Initialize you `views` inside oncreate while holding a global reference in class

Comment: `EditText password = new EditText(findViewById(R.id.passEditText))` how did you come up with this? where did you find that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.) create references inside class to use it later in `enterUPButton` function

```
public class LogIn extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText username,password ;
```

2.) Initialize view inside `onCreate`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_log_in);
    username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.userEditText);
    password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.passEditText);
}
```

Update :

`new EditText` mean creating a new object of `EditText` class but `findViewById(R.id.userEditText)` will return a `View` object so the statement will be `new EditText(View)` but the issue is there is no constructor in [`EditText`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html) class which use `View` as parameter so two issues here ,

- [`findViewById`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#findViewById(int)) should be used inside `oncreate`
- There is no constructor in `EditText` class which takes `View` object as parameter

`password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.passEditText);` mean we are fetching the reference of `EditText` object tag from `XML`.

Comment: Thank you! I did that and it no longer gives me an error, but it does not work now. When I enter the use and pass listed, and click on the enter button, nothing happens

Comment: never mind! it works! thank you. Can you explain to me exactly what changing new EditText to (EditText) exactly does?

Comment: @backwardforward try the update section and i am glad that i could help , happy coding

Answer (score 1):

The new keyword you were using creates a new object of type EditText.
When you write the code:

```
findViewById(R.id.passEditText)
```

It returns the id of the EditText view from your XML.  Since it returns an id and you actually want an EditText variable in your code, you must cast it to an EditText type.  So we add (EditText) just before the findViewById command to cast it, like so:

```
(EditText) findViewById(R.id.passEditText)
```

Next you set that to your variable called password in your java code by giving a type and variable name like this:

```
EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passEditText);
```

Hope that helps.